# restkit & offline mode & view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, restkit

I've a project using restkit (on iOS 6). It work fine in online mode.
Now, i'm trying to implement offline mode. There is two view controllers:

- `LoginViewController : UIViewController`
- `MainSplitViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, RKRequestDelegate>`

On `LoginViewController`, i check if device is offline. If it is, i check if there are login information in a keychain. If so, i go directly on my `MainSplitViewController`. The problem : my `MainSplitViewController` is correctly instanciated, viewDidLoad & viewDidAppear are correctly called, but my view did not appear, and login view stay in place.
Problem appear in offline mode only, so i suspect RestKit to do something wrong... but normally, my navigation controller is independant from RestKit, isn't it?

Comment: UPDATE : viewWillDisappear seems to be not called when in offline mode, in LoginViewController.

Comment: UPDATE 2 : in my AppDelegate, [[self windows] subviews] is empty when i'm in offline mode, so i can't remove LoginViewController from super view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok soooooooooo finally : i said to my LoginViewController "hey go to MainSplitViewController" in viewWillAppear. Move the code in viewDidAppear solved the problem...